# ValueError: continuous is not supported. What is this error?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I tried using Scikit Learn's `classification_report()` to find other details why I got a certain score but instead I got an error.

> **ValueError**: continuous is not supported

I just want to know what it is and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are trying to classify a continuous value. When the values are continuous you need to perform a regression. If you want to perform a classification you then perform a classifier in which you assign the features to a class (group).